# How to know project was created using Eclipse or NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have java application source, but I don't know which IDE was used to create it. I would like to build this project with less setup changes as possible. How to know this project was build using Eclipse or NetBeans?

upd:
there are two xml files in root directory called `app-checks.xml` (this file contais reference to Eclipse plugin and Puppy Crawl) and `pom.xml` (this file contains reference to maven). There are no `.nbproject` or `.classpath/.project` files in whole project.

Which IDE is best to use to open this project?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see some files like .classpath, .project in the project directory then it is probably created using Eclipse. If it was created with NetBeans, you would find some file named like .nbproject.

As for the new question of which IDE is best, there are tons of wars around which IDE is best. I prefer Eclipse, others prefer IntelliJ IDEA, others prefer NetBeans or others. They all know to open a Maven based project. For instance, I use the m2eclipse plugin for importing to Eclipse workspace.

Comment: (Unless it's a Maven project - can't say for Eclipse how this treated, no experience in this area ;))

Comment: If it's a Maven project, if you want to actually use Eclipse as an IDE and not as a notepad, you still need to have .project and .classpath :)

Comment: I have updated question. There are no .nbproject .classpath files in this project, but some xml files resists